# i want to print helloworld recursively `no` times

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to print `helloworld` recursively `no` times. I want this code in this way:

```
import java.util.*;

class ddr {
    //int n;

    static void hh(int n){
        if(n<1)  System.out.println("ffbdf");
        hh(n-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       int no = in.nextInt();

       ddr k = new ddr();
       hh(no);
       //hh(no);
    }
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

Use this Code :

```
import java.util.*;

class ddr
{
//int n;

static void hh(int n)
{

   if(n>0)
   {  
        hh(n-1);
        System.out.println("Hello World!!");
   }

}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int no = in.nextInt();
    hh(no);

}
}
```

Comment: function HelloWorld(count)
{
    if(count<1)returnprint("Hello World!")
    HelloWorld(count - 1)
}

Answer (score 1):

Your method has no stopping condition. The recursion will run forever.

You should only make the recursive calls as long as n > 0.

And if you print your `String` after each recursive call, it will be printed `n` times.

```
static void hh(int n) {
    if(n>0){
        hh(n-1);
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The pseudo-code you are quoting seems to be missing a new-line, which makes it hard to understand. It should be:

```
function HelloWorld(count)
{
    if(count<1) return
    print("Hello World!")
    HelloWorld(count - 1)
}
```

And in Java:

```
void HelloWorld(int count)
{
    if(count < 1)
        return;
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    HelloWorld(count - 1);
}
```

Comment: function HelloWorld(count)
{
    if(count<1)returnprint("Hello World!")
    HelloWorld(count - 1)
}

Comment: i read this in topcoder documentaion and i am trying to do that

Comment: @NaveenVerma is it supposed to be Java? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: yes its psedocode not java but that recursive approch is different i think

Comment: https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/an-introduction-to-recursion-part-1/

Comment: @NaveenVerma I think that presudocode is missing a new line . They probably meant : `if(count<1)return; print("Hello World!"); HelloWorld(count - 1);`. i.e. the only statement executed when count<1 is return. It's quite similar to my code - the only difference is that it prints before the recursive call, and I print after the recursive call.